# Adding input options generated from backend

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sweetalert

I have a little problem with this code included beneath. This is function of library called Sweet Alert 2. I'd like to have "inputOptions" loaded from php

Code I have right now:

```
    function pick(){
    swal({
  title: 'Choose country',
  input: 'select',
  inputOptions: {
    'SRB': 'Serbia',
    'UKR': 'Ukraine',
    'HRV': 'Croatia'
  },
  inputClass: 'form-control select',
  confirmButtonColor: '#78339b',
  inputPlaceholder: 'choose country',
  showCancelButton: true,
}).then(function(result) {
  swal({
    type: 'success',
    html: 'You selected: ' + result
  })
});
}
```

I'd like to have part with input Options like this:

```
<?php
$ct = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE typ = 1",$link);                                             
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ct)){
echo $row['id'] : $row['country'];
}
?>
```

I know this won't work but you know what I mean. Can someone actually help me? I would genuinely appreciate any tips on how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get your options by sending request via  `$.post` in jQuery to your php file :

```
function pick(){
$.post("option.php", {options: options}, function(result){
        if(result){
swal({
  title: 'Choose country',
  input: 'select',
  inputOptions: result,
  .
  .
  .

 });
}
....
```

for php file should be like this:

```
// you can get the data you need by senting option to your page $_POST['options']    
$ct = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE typ = 1",$link);           
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ct)){
        $data[$row['id']] = $row['country'];
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
```

**EDIT**

If you don't want to dynamically get the options you can add them to your code when you make your page:

```
<?php 
$ct = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE typ = 1",$link);           
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($ct)){
        $data[$row['id']] = $row['country'];
    }
?>
<scirpt>
function pick(){
    swal({
  title: 'Choose country',
  input: 'select',
  inputOptions: <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>,
  inputClass: 'form-control select',
</scirpt>
```

Comment: for example if you want some different `typ` you can sent it with POST and then replace `1` with `$_POST['options']` or just ignore it and change it to this : `$.post("option.php", function(result){...`